# Rails internationalization: %{record} is not being translated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I have this on my rails.pt-BR.yml:

```
br:
  errors:
    format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
    messages:
      restrict_dependent_destroy:
        one: "Não é possível excluir o registro pois existe um %{record} dependente"
        many: "Não é possível excluir o registro pois existem %{record} dependentes"
```

In my model, I have this:

```
has_many :entities, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

Whenever restrict_dependent_destroy is triggered, %{record} is showing the model name (plural) in english, and is not being translated, like this: "Não é possível excluir o registro pois existem entities dependentes".

I have another file that contains the translation for :entities

```
br:
  activerecord:
    models:
      entities: 'entidades'
```

Where do rails get the translation for %{record}? Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you calling this because I think you would need to pass `record` as a `hash` through translate. Also I think with pluralization like this it is looking for `%{count}` so it can say `1 dependent` or `2 dependents` but I am not great with `I18n`. Try this [Link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `:restrict_with_error` message (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10787).

As a workaround you can use:

```
br:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      entity: # Should be the parent class when bug https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10787 is fixed
        entities: 'entidades'
```

Comment: what about if you need to have in this activerrecord - attributes -entity: `one: "entidad" other: "entidades"` ?, in my case the restrict_dependent_destroy message is getting the `one` ("entidad") instead of `many` "entidades". this is a problem, any suggestion ?

Comment: @AlbertCatalà this bug has been fixed in Rails 5.0 Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.1.5, and I have a translation equivalent to this 'entities' for 'one' and another for 'other' and the restric_dependent_destroy message is showing the 'one' translation, eventhough I have a `has_many` relation and the relation found has more than one record

Comment: I solved changing the translation removing the `one` and `other` translations, and leaving only the `other` on the `entities`